# IFrame Comet response contains no data

Tags: php, javascript, http, iframe, comet

I'm experimenting with Comet and I'm stuck with implementing it via a hidden IFrame ("forever frame".

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    cometResponse = function() {
        var debugOut = document.getElementById('debugOutput');
        return function(response) {
            debugOut.innerHTML = response.number; 
        }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="debugOutput"></div>
    <iframe src="comet.php"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the comet.php file:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
header('Content-Type: text/html');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
flush();
ob_flush();

$response = '<script type="text/javascript">
parent.cometResponse({
    number: %1$d
});
</script>';

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    sleep(1);
    $data = sprintf($response, $i);
    $output = strtoupper(dechex(strlen($data)))."\r\n".$data."\r\n";
    echo $output;
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
echo "0\r\n\r\n";
```

After loading the page, the browser seems to "wait" for the response. After a few seconds, Firebug shows an empty response with these response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 26 Jul 2010 09:34:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.2.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.12
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-2
```

Since the response is treated as empty, the  tag that should be in the response doesn't get executed either.

However, if I remove the "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header, the content is sent to the browser correctly but all in one big piece at the end of the script, as expected.

I just can't find what's going wrong here.

Comment: Any improvemtns on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two guesses:

1. Content-Encoding: gzip

   Maybe mod_gzip does not work correctly?
   Have you tried on annother host?
2. Maybe Firefox ignores the code, if
   it is not within < html>

Comment: 1. Maybe, i'll look into that. 2. No, Firebug usually displays the raw content of the responses.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone else, here is how I solved it:

```
<?php
header('Content-Encoding: chunked');
header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
header('Content-Type: text/html');
header('Connection: keep-alive');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
flush();
set_time_limit(0);
function chunk($data) {
    echo sprintf("%x\r\n%s\r\n", strlen($data), $data);
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
// Code to output data here.
// The following loop is an example.
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    chunk('<script type="text/javascript">window.top.test();</script>');
    sleep(1);
}
chunk('');
?>
```

It needed an empty chunk at the end of the output.

Then you can simply output data by calling the function `chunk` like this:

```
chunk('data');
```